# Multiple random lines from text file without repetitions

Tags: php, for-loop, random

the code below chose (without repetitions) a random line from a txt file.

```
$filename = "randomlines.txt"; 
$how_many_to_show = 10; 
if ($random = file($filename)) { 
 shuffle($random); 
 for ($i = 0; $i < $how_many_to_show; $i++) { 
  $color[$i]=$random[$i]; 
 } 
} else { 
 die('Could not get contents of: ' . $filename); 
}
```

It works fine. When i put the following string

```
    print($fileContents[$i]. '<br />');
```

in place of this

```
$color=$random[$i];
```

i see on my screen 10 different lines, picked up from randomlines.txt

However i need to associate each different random line to 10 different variables (es. $color1, $color2....$color10) for my subsequent code.

Comment: your explanation is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I tried to write the text in a different way. is that ok? sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent is not so clear to me... Why not using array `colors`, instead of single variables?
Using a single array is simple:

```
$color[$i] = $random[$i];
```

If you really want to use single variables, you could just do:

```
${"color" . $i} = $random[$i];
```

For example, the code

```
<?php 
    $random[0] = 'red';
    $random[1] = 'blue';
    $random[2] = 'green';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
      ${"color" . $i} = $random[$i];
    }

    print $color0 . "\n";
    print $color1 . "\n";
    print $color2 . "\n";
?>
```

Produces:

```
red
blue
green
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I explain me better: the for loop picks a random line from a txt file called randomlines.txt
In the code i set  $how_many_to_show = 10 
So i need 10 different $variables to use in the next code having 10 different values:
$color1... color10
Each of these should have a different color #CEFECC... #FFA117 picked from the lines of randomlines.txt     :)

Comment: Thank you!
I added the code line you suggested `${"color" . $i} = $random[$i];` and i fixed my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of arrays so it looks like:

```
$lines = array(
  array(
    'color' => '#f00',
    'line' => 'First random line.'
  ),
  array(
    'color' => '#ff0',
    'line' => 'Second random line.'
  ),
);
```

Here is the code I came up with, untested:

```
$lines = file('randomlines.txt');
$colors = array('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green');

shuffle($lines);
shuffle($colors);

$output = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
  $output[] = array('line' => $lines[$i], 'color' => $colors[$i]);
}
```

Comment: I explain me better: the for loop picks a random line from a txt file called randomlines.txt In the code i set $how_many_to_show = 10 So i need 10 different $variables to use in the next code having 10 different values: $color1... color10 Each of these should have a different color #CEFECC... #FFA117 picked from the lines of randomlines.txt :)